# how to use Array.prototype.filter with object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to find proper way to use Array prototype filter method in my google sheet to convert current user by email to name, I'm not a programmer please excuse my skills.

i have this type of obj:

```
let userlist [{ "name": "xxx", "email": "xxx@gmail.com" },
{ "name": "yyy", "email": "yyy@gmail.com" },
{ "name": "zzz", "email": "zzz@gmail.com" }];
```

im geting the user email from this:

```
let userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId()
```

and trying to use this to return the user name:

```
    userlist.filter(function (item) {
        return item.name ............;
```

Comment: userList is input, and the desired output is what?

Comment: what are you trying to filter? if you want to convert, perhaps you need to use map() instead.

Comment: Please edit your question and add information about how you wish the object to be filtered. You have not added enough info at this time to help .

Comment: Sorry i should have explained in more detail, im getting the user email from: Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId(), and im trying to filter out and return the name associated with that address from that userlist object

Comment: As  it seems Soza wanst to find one user with a given email. So Array method find seems more appropriate. But filter works too, just know it returns an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you get the email form somewhere and somehow, just find the object with that name inside the array of objects and then access the ame property:

```
let userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
let user = userlist.find(function (item) {
  return item.email === userEmail;
}
let userName = user.name;
```

Similarly with `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
let userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
let users = userlist.filter(function (item) {
  return item.email === userEmail;
}
let userName = user[0].name;
```

You can define a funciton for this by those above:

```
function findUserByEmail(email, userlist) {
  return userlist.find(function (item) {
    return item.email === email;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let user = findUserByEmail(email, userlist);
```

then you can access the name property; `user.name`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of the names then, as suggested, use map.

```
const names = userlist.map(user => user['name']);
```

If you want to get the name for a particular email use filter.

```
let user = userlist.filter(user => user.email === userEmail);

let name = user[0].name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be done with filter():

```
const [user] = userList.filter(user => user.email === userEmail)
const {name = ''} = user || {};
```

or with javascript's new optional chaining feature (Node.js 14+):

```
const name = userList.filter(user => user.email === userEmail)?.[0]?.name || '';
```

Variable name will be either the name if there is a match, empty string otherwise.  This way you can just print name and it will either shows the name or just blank.